# Closed connected subsets of the plane

Tags: general-topology

Does any closed connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with at least two points contain a non-constant continuous curve?

Comment: What's your definition of a continuous curve? Many would say the constant function is.

Comment: Have you considered the set $\{(0,0),(1,0)\}$?

Comment: @DanRust I mean the image of a non-constant continuous function $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @DanRust what is a pseudo-arc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Pseudo-arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-arc) is a totally path-disconnected and connected compact subset of the plane, as required.